# Java Stdin Cannot convert from String[] to String, but inputs are String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, stdin

I am doing a programming assignment that takes all of its input from stdin. The first input is an int n to tell you how many strings will follow, and the next n inputs are strings of varying lengths. The goal is to find the longest string(s) and print them.

I thought this was easy, but for the life of me, I cannot get the stdin to work with me. The eclipse arguments entered are (separated by enter):

- 3
- a2
- b3c
- 7

Yet I run the program, and it tells me it cannot convert from String[] to String. I do not understand how any of the above are String[]. The code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A2P1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        
        String[] str = new String[size];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        

        for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
            str[i] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");              // The error
            //str[i] = sc.next();                         This line and the line below throw
            //str[i] = sc.nextLine();                    no errors, but also gives no output.
        }
        
        String[] longest = new String[size];
        String[] temp = new String[size];
        longest[0] = str[0];
        int numToBeat = str[0].length();
        int k = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
            if (str[i].length() > numToBeat) {
                numToBeat = str[i].length();
                k = 0;
                longest = temp;
                
                longest[k] = str[i];
                k++;
            }
            else if (str[i].length() == numToBeat) {
                longest[k] = str[i];
            }
        }
            
        System.out.println("The longest input strings are:");
        for (int i=0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.println(longest[i]);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Tried:

- Changing str[i] = sc.nextLine().split(" "); to its other variations in the code
- Changing input values
- Googling stdin for the last hour trying to find any documentation that helps me

Comment: The `split` method creates and returns a `String[]` from a `String`.

Comment: *"Googling stdin for the last hour trying to find any documentation that helps me"* - Try looking at the javadocs for the `String` class.  And look at what is says about `split`.   This is not a problem with "stdin" *per se* ... or even with `Scanner`.  It is about what you are doing with the line **after** you read it.  But if all you are doing is reading `size` strings separated by whitespace, you should be using `Scanner.next()` rather than `Scanner.nextLine()`.  (Again ... read the javadocs for `Scanner`.)

Comment: If each input is on its own line, you don't need `split`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse arguments separated by enter then your logic is wrong:

according to your logic get 1st element from the eclipse argument like **args[0]**

another Input is taken from the console.

if you need to take all elements from the eclipse argument follow the below code:

```
public class A2P1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String[] str = new String[size];
        int length=0;
        String loggestString="";
        
        for (int i=1; i < size; i++) {
            str[i] = args[i];      
            int strLen = str[i].length();
            if(strLen>length) {
                length=strLen;
                loggestString=str[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(loggestString);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is incorrect, use the following.

```java
str = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
```

You were attempting to place the `String[]` within the `i` index.

- `str[i]` is a `String`.
- `split` returns a `String[]`

I've refactored your code, for reference, have it look.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] str = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
int maximum = 0;
for (String string : str) {
    if (string.length() > maximum)
        maximum = string.length();
}
System.out.println("The longest input strings are:");
for (String string : str) {
    if (string.length() == maximum)
        System.out.println(string);
}
```

Output for "3 a2 b3c 7".

```
The longest input strings are:
b3c
```